# Vuepress README.doc first page in format yaml convert to markdown format doc

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I am not able to find information on how to modify the main page of Vuepress, which, although I like its structure, being in .yaml format does not allow me to put links.

Is it possible to put links?
Or better, is it possible to convert that page to markdown format but keeping the output it delivers?

[image: Front of vuepress. I like it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible without modifying the Vue templates. The home page is rendered by the [`Home` component](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/7cf8386472e8277cc0088e9080c8afb63907ff72/packages/%40vuepress/theme-default/components/Home.vue) component and it renders the page's frontmatter using Vue's ["Mustache" syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text). Values inside the mustaches will only ever be rendered as plain text.

You'll have to modify the `Home` component by either ["ejecting"](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#ejecting) the default theme or by creating a [custom layout](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#custom-layout-for-specific-pages) for the home page. In both cases, you will obviously not receive any updates to the components anymore when you upgrade Vuepress.

I've created a [demo](https://github.com/delenamalan/vuepress-home-page-links) to show how to use a custom layout to allow the frontmatter to be HTML. I've copied the `Layout` and `Home` components from Vuepress and changed the new `Home` component to use [`v-html`](https://github.com/delenamalan/vuepress-home-page-links/blob/master/docs/.vuepress/components/Home.vue#L16) to inject HTML values into the `h1` component. So now your `heroText` could be `Hi! This is a <a href='https://www.google.com'>link</a>` and it will be displayed as a link on the home page. You could obviously do the same for the other elements.

Be sure to set the `layout` value of your home page to the new layout, e.g. `layout: HomeLayout`.

Comment: A lot of thanks for you demo repo. As I thought, everything goes through remaking code and it is not a quick solution. I only use Vuepress for small manuals, for my clients, because I like to use markdown. But if I have to touch vue, and use advanced plan I choose other solutions. Anyway thank you so much